# php extracting complete url with variables

Tags: php

Using Php I would like to extract the current Url of a page including all variables attached to it.
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] only return the url without the variable . any idea what function I need.

example : www.site.com/?v1=xyz&v2=123

using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] I get only : www.site.com as opposed to the whole url.
using $_GET[] individually is not an opton since I am not sure what variable are attached to the URL.

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could output the content of the `$_SERVER` super-global variable : there are many interesting things in there ;-)

For example, calling a page with an URL like this :

```
http://localhost/temp/temp.php?a=10&b=glop
```

And using :

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

I get at least :

```
array
  ...
  'HTTP_HOST' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  ...
  'REQUEST_METHOD' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  'QUERY_STRING' => string 'a=10&b=glop' (length=11)
  'REQUEST_URI' => string '/temp/temp.php?a=10&b=glop' (length=26)
  'SCRIPT_NAME' => string '/temp/temp.php' (length=14)
  'PHP_SELF' => string '/temp/temp.php' (length=14)
  'REQUEST_TIME' => int 1270060299
```

In there, I suppose at least those could interest you :

- `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` : contains the whole query string ; i.e. the list of all parameters and their values
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` : contains the requested URI -- including the parameters

Answer (score 3):

```
$request = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

For the entire path and Query strings.

Comment: Wouldn't that duplicate the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to retrieve the variables part.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found so far is this one: http://hayageek.com/php-get-current-url/

```
function getCurrentURL() {
    $currentURL = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
    $currentURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];

    if($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80" && $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "443") {
        $currentURL .= ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"];
    } 

    $currentURL .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    return $currentURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two lines:

```
$base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

url = $base_url . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```